# Test method fails (unit-testing in VS)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

I'm working on a laboratory practical with unit-testing. Below is the application that i'm testing (i'm testing all the methods and the constructor). All my tests are complete accept for one, that is testing a method called "isScalene()", that checks wether the triangle is a scalene (all sides are unique) or not.

You find the test method that fails at the bottom. When I change "equalateral" to True and "scalene" to False, it passes. Something is wrong in the application, but I just can't figure out what it is (probably in "uniqueSides() though).

I would be grateful if someone could help me out!

```
public class Triangle {
  double[] sides;

  public Triangle(double a, double b, double c) {
      if ((a <= 0) || (b <= 0) || (c <= 0)){
          throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Sidorna måste vara större än 0.");
      }
    sides = new double[] { a, b, c };
  } 

  private int uniqueSides() {
    return sides.Distinct<double>().Count();
  }

  public bool isScalene() {
      if (uniqueSides() == 1){
          return true;
      }
      else{
          return false;
      }
  }

  public bool isEquilateral() {
      if (uniqueSides() == 3){
          return true;
      }
      else{
          return false;
      }
  }

  public bool isIsosceles() {
      if (uniqueSides() == 2){
          return true;
      }
      else{
          return false;
      }
  }
}
```

...

```
    [TestMethod()]
    public void isScalene3Test3()
    {
        Triangle triangle = new Triangle(25, 250, 2000);

        var isosceles = triangle.isIsosceles();
        var equalateral = triangle.isEquilateral();
        var scalene = triangle.isScalene();

        Assert.IsFalse(isosceles, "Test Isosceles");
        Assert.IsFalse(equalateral, "Test Equalateral");
        Assert.IsTrue(scalene, "Test Scalene");
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

isEquilateral should use 1 unique side, and isScalene should use 3.

```
public class Triangle {
  double[] sides;

  public Triangle(double a, double b, double c) {
      if ((a <= 0) || (b <= 0) || (c <= 0)){
          throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Sidorna måste vara större än 0.");
      }
    sides = new double[] { a, b, c };
  } 

  private int uniqueSides() {
    return sides.Distinct<double>().Count();
  }

  public bool isScalene() {
      if (uniqueSides() == 3){
          return true;
      }
      else{
          return false;
      }
  }

  public bool isEquilateral() {
      if (uniqueSides() == 1){
          return true;
      }
      else{
          return false;
      }
  }

  public bool isIsosceles() {
      if (uniqueSides() == 2){
          return true;
      }
      else{
          return false;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh, how could I have been so blind? ;) Thanks! :)

Comment: Lol. Such a simple mistake. You defined in your question that scalene is a triangle with all 3 sides equal. :P

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want to check if `(uniqueSides() == 3)` rather than 1?

Anyway, debugging the code would have helped you find this out very quickly for yourself.